# $n! \le n^n$, $\forall$ $n \ge 1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that $n! \le n^n$, $\forall$ $n \ge 1$.

It is so difficult, please help me solve it. Thank you.

Comment: It would not be difficult if you wrote both things as products.

Comment: Hint: $k \le n$, $\forall$ $k \le n$.

Comment: Try induction, dividing, anything.

Comment: Hey guys, for you is easy, but there are some people who need help to start  developing his skills. Don't give downvote please

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 4):

Indeed,

$$n! = n \cdot (n-1)  \cdots 2 \cdot 1  \le \underbrace{n\cdot n \cdots n \cdot n}_{n \text{ terms}} = n^n.$$

Or, proceeding by induction, we have $1! \le 1^1$. Now suppose that $n! \le n^n$ for some $n$. Then,

$$(n+1)! = (n+1)n! \le (n+1)n^n < (n+1)(n+1)^n = (n+1)^{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 4):

It does not require induction if you do not want to.

$$\frac{n!}{n^n} = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n} \leq \prod_{k=1}^n 1 = 1$$

and therefore

$$n! \leq n^n$$